# Display top 6 posts at different blocks at homepage Wordpress?

Tags: php, wordpress, wordpress-theming

I want to display top 6 posts of category 'Business' in my home page which looks like this. [[Please take a look at the image]](https://i.stack.imgur.com/vkXPk.png)

Is it possible to query the posts in the 'for' loop ?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can do this of course. But it would be easier if firstly you store them in some array variable, and then place it to any complex grid you want.

F.e.

```
<?php
$business=get_posts("cat=222&posts_per_page=6");

//now put it anywhere you want
?>
<div><?php echo $business[0]->post_title; ?> </div>
...
<div><?php echo $business[5]->post_title; ?> </div>
```